# c++ console Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I`m trying to use pointers to multi-dismentional array that is my map, so in the last code I can use pointer, instead of making collisions for every map. Unfortunatelly, after the map is drawn, when I press arrows to move, program crashes. 
debugger told me only what is in the title

this is one of the maps:

```
char *map2[15] = {      
"###^######^###",      
"#L           #",
"^S           #",
"#S           #",
"#    K       #",
"###########  #",
"#G           #",
"#       #### #",
"#       #M   #",
"# @     #    #",
"## ########^##"};
```

this is the begining:

```
        mainmap = false;
        x = 2;
        game.showing_different_maps(15, map2);    // (y, somemap)
```

showing map and moving:

```
void Game::showing_different_maps(int y, char **somemap)
{
bool differentmap = true;
while (differentmap)
{
    system("cls");
    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)  // i < map2[y][]
    {
        cout << somemap[i] << endl; // drawing a map !THIS CAUSES CRASH!
    }

    system("pause>nul");       
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))  
    {
        mapki.move(-1, 0);
    }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
    {
        mapki.move(1, 0);
    }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
    {
        mapki.move(0, 1);
    }
    if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
    {
        mapki.move(0, -1);
    }
}
```

}

script handling collisions:

```
void Maps::move(int V, int H)
{
int y2 = y + V;
int x2 = x + H;
if(map2[y][x2] == ' ' 
|| map2[y][x2] == 'K'
|| map2[y][x2] == 'W')
{
    map2[y][x] = ' ';
    x += H;
    map2[y][x] = '@';
}
if(map2[y2][x] == ' '
|| map2[y2][x] == 'K'
|| map2[y2][x] == 'W')
{
    map2[y][x] = ' ';
    y += V;
    map2[y][x] = '@';
}
```

}

I wanted to write everywhere somemap[][], instead of map2[][], but I can`t check if it works, because of "Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault." crash.

Comment: tl;dr .. well try gdb :) on Linux and Mingw windows run with `gdb ./yourapp` then inside type run and enter.. then `bt` to see where it segfaulted it will help you a lot :)

Comment: The elements of your array are pointing to `const` strings, and modifying those strings is undefined. The compiler should have warned you about the deprecated conversion to `char*`.

Comment: You are trying to do too much without testing. Solve one problem at a time. Start by getting the drawing code working. If you cannot draw the map without crashing, it is unlikely that you can navigate the map. Plus it gets you closer to having a [mcve].

Comment: `x += H; map2[y][x] = '@';` What, how do you think, will happen here if the `x == 0` and the `H == -1`?

Comment: Serge Roussak - I didn't thought about that one, but it will never happen, "#" is a map boundary.     user4581301 - I know, my most important question is how to move on the map (drawing is working, crash happens after it), I pasted last code extra, because that will be my next problem.  molbdnilo - It was, but now the compiler isn`t getting any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here comes from the array of pointer being declared of size 15, but having only 11 initialized elements. That means that the last 4 are initialized to NULL. In fact your declaration for map2 is equivalent to this one:

```
char *map2[15] = {      
"###^######^###",      
"#L           #",
"^S           #",
"#S           #",
"#    K       #",
"###########  #",
"#G           #",
"#       #### #",
"#       #M   #",
"# @     #    #",
"## ########^##",
NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL};
```

By itself, this would be harmless but you later use:

```
game.showing_different_maps(15, map2);    // (y, somemap)
```

So you end passing null character pointers to `cout <<` so the  SIGSEGV.

You should at least pass the initialized array size, here 11 instead of 15:

```
game.showing_different_maps(11, map2);    // (y, somemap)
```

But I suspect you will have later a problem in `move`, because you should test that 0 <= y+V < VMAX and 0 <= x+H < HMAX (with VMAX = 11 and HMAX = 14 here). If you do not, you could try to access your strings or string array outside their range invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: You're genius, it fixed my problem, but created another one in the last code sample:   map2[y][x] = ' ';    This line is giving me another SIGSEGV error. Of course to save huge amount of space and work, I want that to be the same pointer "somemap". So close to a relief, one last problem and I can dive into my project and program things I know how. I kind of exaggerated with this map system...     Btw. I've made that test, but to be honest, previously I tried to check what happens, If y = 0 etc. and it seems it`s somehow blocking me from doing this without crashing.

Comment: actually, when I try to escape the map from random direction, I always just meet invisible barriers, with no crash. (it was in my last working demo)

Comment: I've changed variables, so it is clear, y,x are coordinates, y1, x1 are map width and height